# sort array of objects by object field

Tags: javascript

I build an array like this

```
result.push({ id: id, reference: sometext });
```

Now I want to sort this array by `reference`, which has some text.

I tried this:

```
result.sort(function(a,b) {
    return result[a]-result[b];
});
```

This

```
[ { id: 1, reference: 'banana' },
{ id: 2, reference: 'apple' } ]
```

should get

```
[ { id: 2, reference: 'apple' },
{ id: 1, reference: 'banana' } ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
result.sort(function(a,b) {
// Compare reference
if(a.reference < b.reference) {
   // a's reference is lesser than the one in b
   return -1;
} else if (a.reference == b.reference) {
   // Both reference params are equal
   return 0;
} else {
   // a's reference is greater than that of b
   return 1
}
});
```

This will return a sorted version of the results array.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this instead:

```
result.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.reference < b.reference ? -1 : 1;
});
```